# Flask Template not found, template placed in adjacent folder

Tags: python, flask

I'm having an issue with my flask app not finding the template that I've placed in the adjacent template folder.

Here is the route I'm using to render_template for the web page, and accompanying relevant code:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='app/templates', static_folder='static')
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/dashboard')
@cross_origin()
def dashboard():
    print('dashbaording')
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Handle preflight requests (CORS)
        response = make_response()
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
        return response
    app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    template_path = os.path.join(app_root, 'templates')
    print("Template folder path:", template_path)
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

Here's the error I'm looking at

> raise TemplateNotFound(template)
> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: dashboard.html

Here's a quick look from my IDE at where I've got the html stored:

[image: IDE file structure view]

If providing the full js, flask app, and html would be useful I would be happy to provide along with any other resources.

Answer (score 1):

You specified that your `templates_folder` is in `app/templates` when it should be `templates` (judging by your file structure).

This should fix it:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
```

Comment: when I try that I get this error from my browser
'''
Your file couldn’t be accessedIt may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
'''
and this in the browser's console
'''
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ VM10:5
'''
sorry I can't seem to figure out how to add code block to comments...

Comment: Here's what the browser error looks like https://imgur.com/a/9WRiCTH

Comment: You need to run your Flask server first then access the `/dashboard` route from http://localhost:5000/dashboard (this depends on your setup).

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty confident that's what I'm doing, I can see the flask server returning a 200 response code, and the return(render_template()) is happening, so flask is finding the html file, the browser just can't display it for some reason.  That particular html file is nothing special just a header, and it opens fine if I put the file path straight to it in my browser.

Comment: I was previously offering advice in the Reddit thread here: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/16nrvry/getting_a_templatenotfound_error_i_cannot_explain/

I’m not certain but I suspect the new error is because you’re not actually on the flask app website domain, you’re looking at an HTML file, so when you ask the browser to redirect to /dashboard it redirects to the file C:/dashboard, which obviously doesn’t exist. This matches up with the error message at least. The solution here is to host the initial webpage on flask as well, and then it should redirect correctly.

Comment: Hello @quickpocket!  I have solved this issue using some of your advice on the reddit thread.  The problem was not with the flask app at all or CORS, but with the js I was using to handle the redirect.  I was doing window.location.href('/dashboard') but what solved it was placing the absolute file path within this function.  Thank you a lot for your attention and help, this issue had me stuck for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by a reddit user.  This issue in the end was caused by an error in the js, which used window.location.href('/dashboard').  I replaced the relative file path here with the absolute file path and it worked.  Thank you to all participants I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Feel free to mark undesirable’s answer as correct since it’s the solution to the question you asked.